# How to resolve this 'failed to load XML file' error occurred while running my nativescript project?

Tags: android, xml, nativescript

If I run my project by 'ns run android', I obtain the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:My_project_path\platforms\tempPlugin\core\build\intermediates\aapt_friendly_merged_manifests\release\aapt\AndroidManifest.xml: AAPT: error: failed to load XML file: The specified file unfound. (2).

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Failed to build plugin @nativescript/core :
Error: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

When I try the suggested options, I obtain the same error.

Comment: Error says "file unfound".  There are two possibilities 1) The code did not compile and failed to produce the xml file  AndroidManifest.xml 2) The file does not exist or you do not have permission to read.

Comment: How Can I correct it?

Comment: Try access the file with File Explorer and see if you can open the file.  Do you have log files?  See : https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/5649